# How can I send a UDP packet from a device on my network (or a separate network) with python?

Tags: python, sockets, networking, udp

I'm trying to send a UDP packet from devices to my laptop. I've tried the below code on Pythonista on my iPhone, and on my Raspberry Pi.

The code works if I run it from my laptop. But that's not very much use, is it?

The devices are all on the same network, but ideally I would like to be able to do it from a device that's not on the network too. I've set up UDP port forwarding for the port I'm using.

I think the problem is probably something to do with the IPs I'm using, but I'm not sure.

The target ip I'm using is the laptop's public IP. The receiving program is bound to the same IP. I've tried using the local IP of my laptop instead, but then I receive nothing at all

When I run the command on rpi, I use `sudo python send_udp.py`

On both devices, I've tried this code expecting to receive a packet on my laptop containing the message "mess1", but nothing happens. The program doesn't throw any errors, but nothing is received.

```
rec_ip = <receiving_ip>
port = 18
sock = s.socket(s.AF_INET, s.SOCK_DGRAM)
while 1:
    sock.sendto(b'mess1', (rec_ip, port))
    time.sleep(1)
```

Realistically, this will have been asked before, but I've gone through 4 or 5 questions and they're all slightly different. Apologies for that

Comment: When using port forwarding your receiving program should bind to the private IP, since the router translates the IP. In fact, your receiving program shouldn't even be *able* to bind to the public IP. The operating system should raise an error saying "hey, I don't know this IP"

Comment: weirdly enough, my program is perfectly happy to connect to the public IP. I've got the problem fixed now though. the issue was that I was trying to connect through port 18, which is blocked by my ISP @user253751